# Terraform (AWS): How to make a variable, of a child module, accessable in the root module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloud

I have the problem that I've put my security group with some other stuff in a child module. But now I need to reference the ID of the security group in my root module. So now I have to make a variable out of the ID, but how can i get this happen?
I already tried to set it up in the .tfvars in the root module, but because the resource itself is in the child-module I can't reach the securitygroup for its id.
Is there a way to reach data from a child module to use it in the parent .tfvars?

I really would appreciate some help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: create an `output "security_group_id" { ... }` in the child module

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will immediately try it =)